# Figure axes text, ticks and labels

Tags: python

I am struggling to change the axis labels, font type and size for the subplots that I created using the facetGrid function. I would much appreciate some help on how to customise this figure for publication purposes.

[image]

Comment: This depends on what library you are using, such as matplotlib, seaborn, plotly, etc.! You should [edit] your question to include a [mre], as well!

Comment: please add your code

Comment: hi.. "customise this figure for publication purposes." this is incredibly vague and how are we supposed to know that? Can you specify what you want to change?